# Nasty Bathroom Tile Grout - Renter Solutions?

Tags: bathroom, flooring, tile, tiling, rental

We are looking for some solutions. We rent 1 bath apartment in a historic building. The grout on our tile bathroom floor has dissolved across most of the floor and looks nasty. Originally the grout was white, closely matching the tile. Now it's black, chunky, and looks incredibly dirty. When we showed the property manager/maintenance they were not interested in fixing it. We'd like to refresh the grout so it looks nicer and is easier to clean. We can't retile the floor and we'd like to avoid removing the existing grout. The tiles are small hexagons / honeycomb pattern. We were considering re-grouting over the existing grout. Will that work? Are there other solutions to easily refresh the grout that you know of?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. It's not practical to regrout those small hex tiles.
2. Grouting over grout does not last and looks bad quickly
3. Mainly your grout is just very dirty.

So, get a stiff brush, some aggressive grout cleaner from the hardware store, and get to work on it.   Try different products (but don't mix them, follow directions).   If you get it clean but it's stained, try bleach.

I think you'll be pleased enough with the results that you won't want to take on a very difficult regrouting job on a floor that doesn't belong to you.

Comment: Again without mixing chemicals, if you live in a hard water area, limescale remover can help. I accidentally discovered this when descaling my shower head as my shower has a tiled floor.